# How to load select options dynamically - Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I'm a little new to jquery therefore pardon me. I have products in a table with a column for categories.

I also have a repeatable field column named `list_sizes` with options such as title, image and description.

What I'd like to do is load specific products once a category is selected. Example - in categories, select one category should give you only products under it in a select field, select a product should give you only its sizes in the next select box.

[image: screenshot of current view]

Any ideas that are easy would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for this using jQuery to change select options...

```
<script>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                        $("select#jform_category_title").change(function()
                                        {
                                            cid = $(this).val();
                                                    console.log(cid);
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: 'index.php?option=com_orders&task=orderform.getAjaxProducts',
                                                type: 'GET',
                                                dataType: "json",
                                                data: {'cid': cid} ,
                                                success: function(response){
                                                    // this is a joomla JSONResponse object
                                                    // our data is in response.data
                                                    console.log(response);

                                                    if (response.success){
                                                        // create our list of options with response.data
                                                        $("select#jform_product_title option").remove();
                                                        var options = response.data;
                                                        $.each(options, function(i, obj) {
                                                            // obj contains text and value
                                                            jQuery("select#jform_product_title").append( "<option value="+ obj.value +">" + obj.text + "</option>" );

                                                        });
                                                        jQuery("select").trigger("liszt:updated");
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        alert(response.message);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            })
                                        })

                                            $("select#jform_product_title").change(function()
                                            {
                                                subcounty_id = $(this).val();
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    url: 'index.php?option=com_orders&task=orderform.getAjaxSizes',
                                                    type: 'GET',
                                                    dataType: "json",
                                                    data: {'subcounty_id': subcounty_id} ,
                                                    success: function(response){
                                                        // this is a joomla JSONResponse object
                                                        // our data is in response.data
                                                        if (response.success){
                                                            // create our list of options with response.data
                                                            $("select#jform_book_size option").remove();
                                                            var options = response.data;
                                                                        console.log(response.data);
                                                            $.each(options, function(i, obj) {
                                                                // obj contains text and value
                                                                jQuery("select#jform_book_size").append( "<option value="+ obj.value +">" + obj.text + "</option>" );

                                                            });
                                                            jQuery("select").trigger("liszt:updated");
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                            alert(response.message);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            })

                                    });

                                    </script>
```

In the Joomla controller, getAjaxProducts gets products list getAjaxSizes gets sizes.

```
public function getAjaxProducts(){
        $ajax           = true; // redundant
        $category_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('cid');
        $data           = OrdersHelpersOrders::getProductsForSelect($category_id);
        $input          = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        // echo json_encode($data);
        //echo new JResponseJson($data, null, false, $input->get('ignoreMessages', true, 'bool'));
        echo new JResponseJson($data);
        jexit();
    }
```

Remove the default select options in readiness for response.data

```
$("select#jform_product_title option").remove();
```

and finally trigger the change using

```
jQuery("select").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

html for categories select construct becomes

```
<select name="jform[category_title]" class="inputbox" id="jform_category_title">
                                        <option value=""><?php echo JText::_('Select Category'); ?></option>
                                        <?php echo JHtml::_('select.options', $this->subCategories, 'value', 'text', $this->item->cid); ?>
                                    </select>
```

html for products select construct becomes

```
<select name="jform[product_title]" class="inputbox" id="jform_product_title">
                                <option value=""><?php echo JText::_('Select Product'); ?></option>
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('select.options', $this->subProducts, 'value', 'text', $this->item->product_title); ?>
                            </select>
```

html select for sizes like

```
<select name="jform[book_size]" class="inputbox" id="jform_book_size">
                                <option value=""><?php echo JText::_('Select Size'); ?></option>
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('select.options', $this->sizes, 'value', 'text', $this->item->ward_id); ?>
                        </select>
```